# Git command to get the latest from another bitbucket account to my account

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have 2 Bitbucket account.
How I can refresh the code in second bitbucket with the latest from first Bitbucket account.
I already imported all the repositories in the second account but need to refresh the code again.
Is there any git command to do that fast?
I know I can pull from 1st one and push to the second one, but it takes long as it is several repo, I wonder if there is any command that make it faster.

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts or multiple repositories? Also, are the repositories you have write access to forks of the other repositories? If so, setting one (the write one) as your `origin` and the other as your `upstream` will probably be best.

Comment: @AndrewMascillaro - 2 different accounts and Multiples Repositories that need to refresh.

Comment: There is no magic way. You could write a script to do this for all the repositories. It would just give the same commands you are giving, but it would be a single thing.